# How to run a Javascript program automatically after page refresh?

Tags: javascript, refresh

I am wondering if it is possible to have my program which ends with a page refresh, automatically run again after the page refreshes.

Answer (score 1):

call the function(s) you want to run.

```
function doBusiness() {
  // the business
}
doBusiness(); // leave the program where it is but make sure this is outside of any function that isn't called right away
```

If you don't want to do business the first time the page loads, look into sessionStorage, good starting point is [mozilla doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage).  cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
<body onload="yourLoadingFunction()">
```

or

```
document.onload = function(){
   //your code here
}
```

Any of these functions should be included in your  tag in your page.